# Car jerking over 2500 RPM

Tags: cel, chrysler, pt-cruiser

I have a 2006 Chrysler PT cruiser. Sometimes my check engine light comes on and when it does my car starts to jerk if you go past 2500 RPM. And then out of nowhere it stops doing it and the check engine light goes off.

Comment: Have you had the codes checked? They will remain present in the computer even after the CEL turns off. This will give you a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: No. How would i get my codes checked?

Comment: If you are in the States, you can get them read at most any chain parts store for free (O'Reilly's; Checker; AutoZone; Advance, etc.).

Comment: I'd suspect you have a variable valve timing related issue assuming the car isn't misfiring.